# Do stories, such as Prajapati having intercourse with his daughter or creating cattle out of his sperm, have any scriptural basis?

Tags: scripture, brahma, shatapatha-brahmana, brahmanas, ethics

The stories mentioned in the question are from the reference below.
Do these stories have any scriptural basis, and if so, I would like to understand the ethical concerns/dilemmas regarding these stories. It would be nice if you could quote other scriptural passage or comments from some Acharyas that deals with or elaborate on the ethical background of these stories.

Also, is this translation from W.Caland reliable or is it biased?

**Reference:**

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First, links are not acceptable as  questions. You need to write out the reference in your question. Second, reddit is not a scriptural source. The forum is not meant for opinions on reddit, or youtube, etc., etc.

Comment: Which Shashtra is quoted in the reference?